# Adding style to a <div> container in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, css

While trying to add a style to a div container using Vanilla JS, I found that -
`containerDiv.style.backgroundColor = color;` is not same as `document.body.containerDiv.style.backgroundColor = color;`.
Can anyone explain this to me why is it so ?

here is my code -

```
function changeColor(value) {
  var color = document.body.style.backgroundColor;
  const containerDiv = document.querySelector(".container");

  switch (value) {
    case "b":
      color = "#00008B";
      break;

    case "r":
      color = "#8B0000";
      break;

    case "g":
      color = "#00ff00";
      break;

    default:
      color = "#000";
  }
  containerDiv.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

changeColor();
```

Comment: Have you checked for errors using your browser's dev tools?

Answer (score 0):

`containerDiv` is a variable (constant) that contains your `.container` element.

`document.body.containerDiv` is undefined, because `containerDiv` is not part of `document.body` object.

```js
function changeColor(value) {
  var color = document.body.style.backgroundColor;
  const containerDiv = document.querySelector(".container");

  switch (value) {
    case "b":
      color = "#00008B";
      break;

    case "r":
      color = "#8B0000";
      break;

    case "g":
      color = "#00ff00";
      break;

    default:
      color = "#000";
  }
  containerDiv.style.backgroundColor = color;

console.log("document.body.containerDiv = ", document.body.containerDiv);
console.log("containerDiv = ", containerDiv);

}

changeColor();
```

```css
.container
{
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```